# Iframe wrong loading IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

I knwo that IE11 is not the most popular thing ever, but I want to ask for advice because I am stuck in this. Here is the situation I have a page that is responsive and redy to work in widget size. To laod the page in widget size I have a ifrmae that I call like this

```
<iframe scrolling="no" id="myid" style="width:100%;height:517px;border:0;margin:0 0 8px;padding:0;overflow:hidden" src="https://example.com/Controller/action/min?responsive&lang=en&widget"></iframe>
```

and if I want to call the stend alone page I call it like this

```
<iframe scrolling="no" id="myid" style="width:100%;height:517px;border:0;margin:0 0 8px;padding:0;overflow:hidden" src="https://example.com/Controller/action/min?responsive&lang=en"></iframe>
```

This is working perfect for all other browser, but in IE11 even if the JS is detecting correct that here have to be a widget and is making the call with extra paramiter widget, the ifrma load the full content with no changes. I am stuck so ny help can be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure, but IE might somehow normalize the "invalid" query string ..?

Comment: try giving widget a value `?responsive&lang=en&widget=1`